# Unable to run skype 4.3 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, skype

I recently upgraded skype 4.2 to 4.3 on ubuntu 12.04, but it is crashed within some seconds. This crash is happening each time. can any body suggest me some workaround.

Comment: Re-install it by removing the old one. http://askubuntu.com/questions/228065/uninstalling-skype

Answer (score 0):

Skype 4.3 is incompatible with 4.2 files.  Locate both `.Skype` and `.config/Skype` folders in your home folder and delete them.  Normally you do not need to reinstall anything.  Skype 4.3 should run fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
wget -O skype-install.deb http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
```

or Reinstall it using standard Ubuntu Software Center.